# Python simple converter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a new python programmer that is currently developing a really simple converter in python. I currently have this, but I want to make it so 'n' can be changed anytime.

```
#inches to centimeters
def in_inches(n):
    resulti = n * 100
    return resulti

n = 10
resulti = in_inches(n)
print "In %d inches we have %d centimeters" % (n, resulti)

#pounds to kilograms
def in_pounds(x):
    resultp = x * 0.453592
    return resultp

x = 10.0
resultp = in_pounds(x)
print "In %d pounds we have %d kilograms." % (x, resultp)
```

Comment: You can use `input` to get the user to set the value for `n`

Comment: ... the same with `x` too.

Comment: For Python 2, I'd recommend `raw_input`.

Comment: @JulienBernu Actual `input()` is the wrong function. He needs `raw_input()`.

Comment: @leaf agreed, it is obviously the OP is using Py2.X, this is obviously not true for Py3.

Comment: @AChampion Yes. The only reason I pointed this out in the comments is because the OP would become confused when when trying to take Julien's advice. I only hope he sees my first comment....

Comment: Hello thanks for all the answers, but I am starting to see a great difference between py 2 and 3. Which should I learn?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values as `raw_input()` (`input()` for Py3) as mentioned in the comments or you can get them as args to a script. Here's a small example that just collects all of `-i` args to mean `in_inches()` and all the `-p` arguments to mean `in_pounds()`:

```
from __future__ import print_function   # Really should start moving to Py3

#inches to centimeters
def in_inches(n):
    resulti = n * 2.56
    return resulti

#pounds to kilograms
def in_pounds(x):
    resultp = x * 0.453592
    return resultp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--inches', default=[], type=float, action='append')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--pounds', default=[], type=float, action='append')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    for n in args.inches:
        print("In {} inches we have {} centimeters".format(n, in_inches(n)))
    for x in args.pounds:
        print("In {} inches we have {} centimeters".format(x, in_pounds(x)))
```

Then you just call the script with whatever arguments you want:

```
$ python myconverter.py -p 7 -i 42 -p 10 -p 12
In 42.0 inches we have 107.52 centimeters
In 7.0 pounds we have 3.175144 kilos
In 10.0 pounds we have 4.53592 kilos
In 12.0 pounds we have 5.443104 kilos
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def in_to_cen(num):
    return(num * 2.54)
def pds_to_kg(num):
    return(num *0.453592)
while True:
    print "which conversion?"
    print "'1' = pounds to kilograms"
    print "'2' = inches to centimeters"
    choice = raw_input("? ")
    if choice == "1":
        num = input("how many pounds? ")
        res = pds_to_kg(num)
        print str(num) + " is " + str(res) + " Kilograms"
    elif choice == "2":
        num = input("how many inches? ")
        print str(num) + " is " + str(res) + " centimeters."
    else:
        print "invalid choice"
```

This is what I think you are wanting.

This program has a menu asking for which conversion to make, then depending on that choice gets a numerical input from the user, and then outputs the correct conversion.

Comment: `input()` is generally considered harmful in Py2. `int(raw_input(...))` is considered safer, or more flexibly `ast.literal_eval(raw_input(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function and do all the conversions in it instead of making many functions:

```
def convert(n, fromto):
    if fromto == "in_cm":
        print "In %d inches we have %d centimeters" %(n, n*100)
    if fromto == "kg_pound":
        print "In %d pounds we have %d kilograms." %(n, n*0.453592)

convert(2, "in_cm")
convert(5, "kg_pound")
```

Output:

```
In 2 inches we have 200 centimeters
In 5 pounds we have 2 kilograms.
```